Webpack is removing a variable during bundeling
I have a string in a file like this:
const qPrefixes = `
  PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
  ...
`

underneath it I have another string:
const countResultsQuery = `
${qPrefixes}
...
`

When building my app for production, webpack seems to not be including the first variable. I get the error that qPrefixes is not defined. Looking through the bundled code, it does not seem to be included.
Is there somehow I can force webpack to include it
